# JSON schema rule to require property presence if it is mentioned in another property

Tags: json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

Having such JSON:

```
{
  "attribute_1": {
    "some_nested_attribute": {
      "other_attribute_reference": "attribute_2"
    }
  },
  "attribute_2": {
    ...
  }
}
```

`attribute_1, attribute_X` - the names are dynamic, it can also be `blabla-something`, I don't have a fixed property name list. I want to create a JSON schema validation, which would validate the presence of `attribute_2` (or any other not predefined name) in the JSON if it was used in the nested `other_attribute_reference`. I know about [if/else](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html?highlight=else) in JSON schema, but how would I use that when the property name is dynamic and can be almost anything?

Comment: How about combining schemas (https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html) ?

Comment: @TDuong ok but how to use combining? can you give an example?

Comment: Do you have the exact structure that you are going to store like `"attribute_2"`?